# Django/nginx на сервере не отдает sw.js

Tags: django, nginx, static, веб-служба

И так, есть странная проблема... Есть сайт Django на сервере, и решил я прикрутить уведомления. И, как известно, нужен сервис-воркер, который у меня есть и отлично работает локально, но когда я загрузил изменения на сервер, то я обнаружил, что сервер его не видит(в консоле браузера вижу ошибку "***Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://my-domen/') with script ('https://my-domen/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.***", а так же "***A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.***"
Т.е. понятно, что registerSw.js ссылается на sw.js, но Django/nginx не видит его (вся статика подтягивается отлично(В дебаг режиме и нет), но только не sw.js). Вот код
registerSw.js:

```js
const registerSw = async () => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        const reg = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js');
        initialiseState(reg)

    } else {
        showNotAllowed("You can't send push notifications ☹️")
    }
};

const initialiseState = (reg) => {
    if (!reg.showNotification) {
        showNotAllowed('Showing notifications isn\'t supported ☹️');
        return
    }
    if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
        showNotAllowed('You prevented us from showing notifications ☹️');
        return
    }
    if (!'PushManager' in window) {
        showNotAllowed("Push isn't allowed in your browser ");
        return
    }
    subscribe(reg);
}

const showNotAllowed = (message) => {
    const button = document.querySelector('form>button');
    button.innerHTML = `${message}`;
    button.setAttribute('disabled', 'true');
};

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4);
    const base64 = (base64String + padding)
        .replace(/\-/g, '+')
        .replace(/_/g, '/');

    const rawData = window.atob(base64);
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length);
    const outputData = outputArray.map((output, index) => rawData.charCodeAt(index));

    return outputData;
}

const subscribe = async (reg) => {
    const subscription = await reg.pushManager.getSubscription();
    if (subscription) {
        sendSubData(subscription);
        return;
    }

    const vapidMeta = document.querySelector('meta[name="vapid-key"]');
    const key = vapidMeta.content;
    const options = {
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        // if key exists, create applicationServerKey property
        ...(key && {applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(key)})
    };

    const sub = await reg.pushManager.subscribe(options);
    sendSubData(sub)
};

const sendSubData = async (subscription) => {
    const browser = navigator.userAgent.match(/(firefox|msie|chrome|safari|trident)/ig)[0].toLowerCase();
    const data = {
        status_type: 'subscribe',
        subscription: subscription.toJSON(),
        browser: browser,
    };

    const res = await fetch('/webpush/save_information', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: "include"
    });

    handleResponse(res);
};

const handleResponse = (res) => {
    console.log(res.status);
};

registerSw();
```

urls.py:

```
path('home/', home, name='home'),
path('sw.js', serve, {'path': 'my_project/js/sw.js'}),
```

sw.js находится в статике в папке js. Там же, где и registerSw.js
Логи джанго с сервера:
Django.log:

```
Not Found: /sw.js
```

Логи nginx:

```
2023/11/20 17:04:08 [error] 405653#405653: *2251 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: (тут какойто ip, решил не показывать), server: my-site.ru, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/home/", host: "my-domen.ru"
```

2023/11/20 21:33:52 [error] 474557#474557: *11 connect() failed (111: Unknown error) while connecting to upstream, client: (тут какойто ip, решил не показывать), server: my-domen.ru, request: "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/home/", host: "my-domen.ru"

Не уверен, что эти ошибки возникают, из-за sw.js. Проверил 8001 порт и понял, что он просто занят gunicornom, который и запускает сервер.
(Права на św.js я проверял и там все отлично. collectstatic делал, кеш чистил. Единственное различие между локальными файлами и теми, которые на сервере в настройках:
Локаль:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']
```

Сервер:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, я не понимаю как мне решить эту проблему((9(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю на свой же вопрос. Нормальным способом решить это не удалось. (даже если подключать sw в html странице, то хром его видит, словно он начал раздаваться из статики, но nginx/django все равно на это, и они так же не могут найти его). Решение нашел только в том, чтобы явно указать nginx'y полный путь до sw.js. (Как по мне немного костыль, но работает ведь))
Если кому-то понадобится подробная инструкция, то держите путь решения:

1. Открыть конфиг nginx ("sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default" ну или как у вас там он называется)
2. Прописать в конфигурации сервера явный путь к вашему sw.js:

   ```
    location /sw.js {
        alias /home/hostgeek/myapps/path/to/your/static/js/sw.js;
    }
   ```
3. Перезапускайте nginx и радуетесь ("sudo service nginx restart")